# What was the purpose of the Wonder Woman (2013) short?

Tags: short-films

Poking around on IMDB today, I came across a [Wonder Woman listing for 2013](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3439676/?ref_=tt_rec_tt).  I hadn't heard of a Wonder Woman movie, and then I realized it was a 3-minute short.

Was there some "greater purpose" for this short movie?  Was it a test to see how much interest it would generate, to determine if a full-length film was warranted?  Was it done to retain rights, like the infamous Corman version of Fantastic Four?  Why just a 3-minute clip?

Comment: I think this would be a question you'd need to ask the producers of the short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fan-made film from [RainfallFilms](http://rainfall.tv/). It's not an official property of DC comics.

There is nothing much to it. There are so many similar shorts present on DC property like Nightwing etc.

DC has rights for Wonder Woman and they don't have to retain it, its their own property.

Comment: So if it's a rather "inofficial" production without DC's involvement, weren't there any copyright problems, seeing that the film is public enough to have an IMDb entry?

Comment: Sweet!  I'd watch that if they made it full-length.  So they just threw it together for the heck of it?  I'd have to think they had some purpose in mind, even if it was just for a resume or something.  There's quite a bit of CGI in it, which doesn't come free (or cheap).  They did a great job on it.

Comment: I'm sure they put it together to kind of push DC in the direction of starting on a full length film.  I'm sure they didn't just do it for the heck of it.  I'm sure there was a purpose.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Derivative art (fan art) can fall into fair use. My feeling would be that, particularly when they aren't trying to make money off of it, they're usually not going to have issues. Plus, the total value of something like this compared to DC's power is minute, so the chance of "harm" is tiny.